# AngularJS '$onStateChangeSucces' not fired

Tags: angularjs

This event isn't fired and I have ui.router dependency in my app.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options)=>{
        console.log('here')
});
```

Comment: Where are you using these lines? Is the $rootScope injected?

Answer (score 1):

Can't leave a comment to ask you what version of ui-router you're using, but if you're a version >= 1.0, stateChange events are not fired anymore.

From their doc :

> NOTE: State change events are deprecated, DISABLED and replaced by Transition Hooks as of version 1.0

You can see of to use Transition Hooks there : https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events